# datetime picker is not working after page rerender

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, apex

Using Datetimepicker in apex page,Onload is working fine, but after rerender its not working .
code::
used apex inputfield::

```
<apex:inputField value="{!comextnew.Established_Date__c}" styleClass="jqdatepicker" />
```

script::

```
 <script>           
        var dt = jQuery.noConflict();   
        dt(document).ready(function() {                         
        dt('.jqdatepicker').datetimepicker({
        timepicker:false,
        format:'m/d/Y',
        formatDate: 'm/d/Y', 
        });
        })
</script>
```

When i was inspecting its saying that::

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentStyle' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

After my complete research on this issue, i got to know that on page load its loading with HTML5 components and when doing page rerender its not getting components information because page rerender portion was rendered as html4 or lower html version's component.Thats why i found the solution through some script which holds the components information of page when it was loaded and will use the same when you are trying to rerender.Add the below script in page,it will complete task for you.

```
<script>

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "{!URLFOR($Resource.edsr_master, 'edsr_root/js/jquery-1.9.1.js')}";
    script.onload = function() {
        loadJS();
    }
    document.head.appendChild(script);     
    function loadJS() {
        var script1 = document.createElement('script');
        script1.src = "{!URLFOR($Resource.edsr_master, 'edsr_root/js/jquery.datetimepicker.js')}";
        script1.onload = function() {

        }
        document.head.appendChild(script1); 
    }
</script>
```